# Anglular-mdl reactive forms password validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-mdl

I have a password field where I need a validation with following rules:

1. It should be alphanumeric
2. It should not allow only characters or numbers

   ```
               <p>
                   <mdl-textfield 
                   label="Password" 
                   type="password" 
                   formControlName="password1" 
                   floating-label
                   pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
                   error-msg="Please provide an alpha-numeric password"
                   ></mdl-textfield>
               </p>
   ```

How should I write my pattern?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve is using a pipe operator which validates to true if either of the pattern is true. You could try something like this.

```
([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[A-Za-z]+)
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):